# meaning of stringtokenizer with bracket in the delimiter argument in java

Tags: java

I have a code like this.

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, ":(=)");
```

Does it delimit on the basis of ':" or "=" . What is the significance of bracket around equal sign ?

Comment: What happens when you remove the things you don't understand?

Comment: Read the Javadoc for StringTokenizer

Comment: `(` and `)` are also delimiters

Answer (score 5):

Each character in that string is a delimiter for the string to be split on.

[From the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/StringTokenizer.html):

> The characters in the `delim` argument are the delimiters for separating tokens. Delimiter characters themselves will not be treated as tokens.

```
String str = "my:sentence(to=parse)!";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, ":(=)");
while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
    System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

output

```
my 
sentence 
to 
parse 
!
```